# A really sad riddle

Tags: riddle

I'll admit
I'm mostly blue,
but it's not so great to have
something constantly piercing through you.
I might even be in tears,
but I can definitely be beautiful too.

Comment: I think you need to add more clues to make the answer fit uniquely. I find the accepted answer and some of the alternative answers equally compelling.

Comment: @xnor I'll keep that in mind for the next riddle, but I feel that the accepted answer is the only answer that fits all clues perfectly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> The sky

I'll admit
I'm mostly blue,

> Mostly blue, but sometimes cloudy or sunset-y red/pink.

but it's not so great to have
something constantly piercing through you.

> Sunlight is very piercing, and the night sky has been described as "a backlit canopy with holes punched in it", so it's constantly being pierced, day or night.

I might even be in tears,

> The sky crying is rain

but I can definitely be beautiful too.

> If you don't agree the sky can be beautiful, you have no soul :P

Comment: Well done! @Geobits

Comment: I thought the piercing was planes and rocket launches, personally.

Comment: @corsiKa I figured it could go either way, so I went with the more poetic (IMO) one.

Comment: @corsiKa I had both in mind.

Answer (score 6):

Mostly blue

> Oceans are blue, and in large enough quantities water does take on a blue colour regardless of the reflection.

Something piercing through you

> Boats, swimmers, land, straws. Fairly common phrase - a boat piercing the waves.

I might even be in tears

> Tears are made of water

But I can be beautiful too

> Oceans, lakes, rivers, ponds are all gorgeous under the right circumstances.

The answer therefore could be

> Water

Comment: Your first reasoning isn't accurate. The oceans are only blue because they reflect the sky. Water is always clear.

Comment: No that is a common misconception. Water is tinted blue, or more accurately  a turquoise-blue. In large enough quantities you can tell. The reflection of the sky amplifies the colour blue or masks it should the sky be grey, but that is only affecting the colour which we see not the colour the water itself is.

Comment: @corsiKa have you seriously never seen blue sea under a grey sky?

Answer (score 5):

> Eyes

Mostly Blue

> Blue eyes, but white and black as well, but yet we still call them blue.

something constantly piercing through you

> Light pierces through eyes so you can see.

I might be in tears

> Literally swimming in tears when someone cries.

but I can definitely be beautiful too.

> Blue eyes can be very beautiful.

Comment: Great alternative answer!

Answer (score -1):

I thought of

> a tattoo

which is mostly blue

> ink

and might well be pierced by

> - well, by a piercing. Many tattoo places would do that for you too---you might even get a discount.

"I might even be in tears," made me think of

> the way some people get tears tattooed on their cheek, as in the Tom Waits lyric: *...the girl behind the counter has a tattooed tear: "One for every year he's away," she said...*

but [it] can definitely be beautiful too

> depending on the skill of the tattoo artist.